# how to work with json using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, json

this json is on server written which is written in url of $.ajax function.so can any one tell me how to parse this json using jquery or javascript. I validate json using online json validator . json is valid. but still I am finding error.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'http://138.128.162.18:8080/wrtual/Top_content1',
  async: false,
dataType: 'jsonp',
 success: function(data) {

    if($.trim(data) == "false") {
      alert("Fail to recived data");

    }
    else {
      alert("Successfully data recived");
      $('.results').html(data);
    }

  }
});
```

this is the json which i want to parse

```
{"TopContent1":[{"category":"Super Apps","field":"Rank 1","icon":"unnamed_gan.png","name":"Gaana","url":"market://details?id \u003dcom.gaana","pack":""},{"category":"Super Apps","field":"Rank 1","icon":"endomondo.png","name":"Endomondo Sports Tracker","url":"market://details?id\u003dcom.endomondo.android","pack":""}, {"category":"Super Apps","field":"Rank 1","icon":"viber.png","name":"Viber","url":"market://details?id \u003dcom.viber.voip\u0026hl\u003den","pack":""}]}
```

it shows error missing ; before statement on firebug.

Comment: You mean you want to parse an HTTP response body as JSON? Oh, and your code seems to have lost all its quotes.

Comment: What JSON? I can see just jQuery AJAX code here.

Comment: means this url contain a json so i want to get that json data

Comment: it show a error on firebug missing ; before statment

Comment: jQuery will parse it for you. Just make sure the json is valid. You  can validate it using many online validators. Also I hope that is not your real script as there are so many things wrong with it.

Comment: Can you please show us the error and your json?

Comment: {"TopContent1":[{"category":"Super Apps","field":"Rank 

1","icon":"unnamed_gan.png","name":"Gaana","url":"market://details?id

\u003dcom.gaana","pack":""},{"category":"Super Apps","field":"Rank 

1","icon":"endomondo.png","name":"Endomondo Sports 

Tracker","url":"market://details?id\u003dcom.endomondo.android","pack":""},

{"category":"Super Apps","field":"Rank 

1","icon":"viber.png","name":"Viber","url":"market://details?id

\u003dcom.viber.voip\u0026hl\u003den","pack":""}]}

Comment: Try enclosing the data type into quotes: `dataType: "jsonp",`

Comment: @achintsarkar The code in the question is not a verbatim copy of the actual code, right? It's missing a *whole lot* of quotes.

Comment: error:- missing ; before statment

Comment: @achintsarkar please update the OP with JSON feed and the error.

Comment: $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'http://138.128.162.18:8080/wrtual/Top_content1',
      async: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {

        if($.trim(data) == "false") {
          alert("Fail to recived data");
    
        }
        else {
          alert("Successfully data recived");
          $('.results').html(data);
        }

      }
    });

Comment: it still show error:- missing ; before statment

Comment: @achintsarkar Please, please, *please* put all that code in the question instead; it's quite unreadable when it's in comments.

Comment: @achintsarkar That error is most likely caused by a syntax error in your code. (`;` has no significance in JSON.) Is there any way to see on which line the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. But read up on some basics and don't let other people do your work.

```
var parsed_json;

$.get( "http://138.128.162.18:8080/wrtual/Top_content1", function( data ) {
  alert( "Successfully data recived." );
  if(data.length > 0) {
    // response was not empty
    parsed_json = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert("Hooray, response wasn't empty");
  }
});
// Check what we got. Or do what ever you want
console.log(parsed_json);
```

Also don't work with alert(); Rather use console.log(); and the JS Console.

Comment: Error still occured during parsing the data(**ERROR** Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://138.128.162.18:8080/wrtual/Top_content1. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS).

Comment: Response is still empty

Comment: This is a security issue since your script and the data seem to be on different servers. You have to enable CORS. You find more information here: http://bit.ly/WOmDJV